# QGraphicsView background

Tags: qt, background, transparency, qgraphicsview

Hi i'm trying to get a photoshop-like behaviour for my QGraphicsScene

The grid in the background should not resize with the call of scale. And I must be able to save the picture with QPixmap::grabWidget(view) but without the background grid. I can probably do it with removing the background layer just before saving the picture, but i'm not sure if its cleanest way to do it.

Any ideas ?

thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Question 1

> The grid in the background should not resize with the call of scale.

Use the `QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations` [flag](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#GraphicsItemFlag-enum).

> The item ignores inherited transformations (i.e., its position is
>   still anchored to its parent, but the parent or view rotation, zoom or
>   shear transformations are ignored). This flag is useful for keeping
>   text label items horizontal and unscaled, so they will still be
>   readable if the view is transformed. When set, the item's view
>   geometry and scene geometry will be maintained separately.

In order to set this flag use the [`setFlag`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#setFlag) function when creating the grid item.

### Question 2

> I must be able to save the picture with QPixmap::grabWidget(view) but without the
>   background grid.

Call the [`hide`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#hide) function on the grid item before calling the `grabWidget`. After you have grabbed it you show it again by calling the [`show`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#show) function.

Comment: That seems to be it but I was using setBackgroundBrush on the scene for my background in order to repeat the grid pattern from a small image. But how to do it now ? Is it possible to create a QGraphicsItem from a QBrush ?

Comment: Just found the an answer myself : QGraphicsRectItem and the method setBrush()